# Curl with SSO user/pass

Tags: url, curl, automated-tests

I am trying to add monitoring to a Web site to check if it works.

When I go to `https://yy-dev.zzz.com/home` - it asks me for User/Pass in order to SSO into application.

How do I do that using CURL or similar command line utility? How to provide SSO user/pass?

Trying to automate testing..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your website support `HTTP Basic authentication` or `HTTP Digest authentication` or `HTTP NTLM authentication` then curl has native support to login, for example

```
curl -u name:passwd https://yy-dev.zzz.com/
```

***but*** the vast majority of websites out there has their own custom http-based login protocol, and does not support any of the above mentioned schemes. some websites makes it easy to login via libcurl using simple HTTP Post parameters, like in php/libcurl:

```
<?php
$ch=curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch,array(
    CURLOPT_POST=>1,
    CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE=>'', // enables cookie handling, most websites use cookies for logins
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS=>array(
        'username'=>'whatever',
        'password'=>'whatever',
    ),
    CURLOPT_URL=>'https://yy-dev.zzz.com/login',
));
curl_exec($ch);
```

while many sites needs a csrf-token and valid cookie session before allowing login, something like

```
<?php
$ch=curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch,array(
    CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE=>'', // enables cookie handling, most websites use cookies for logins
    CURLOPT_URL=>'https://yy-dev.zzz.com/login',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER=>1
));
$html=curl_exec($ch);
$domd=@DOMDocument::loadHTML($html);
$csrf_token=$domd->getElementById("csrf_token")->getAttribute("value");
curl_setopt_array($ch,array(
    CURLOPT_POST=>1,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS=>array(
        'username'=>'whatever',
        'password'=>'whatever',
        'csrf_token'=>$csrf_token
    ),
    CURLOPT_URL=>'https://yy-dev.zzz.com/login',
));
echo curl_exec($ch); // logged in!
```

... and some websites makes it **NOTORIOUSLY DIFFICULT** to login, for example https://gmail.com , here are 300 lines of code for.. only logging into gmail.com: https://gist.github.com/divinity76/544d7cadd3e88e057ea3504cb8b3bf7e

you need to figure out your website's login protocol. and because you posted neither a link to the website (thus we the SO community can't take a look at it ourselves), nor did you post an analysis of the login protocol your website uses, i have voted to close your question, it doesn't contain enough information to find a solution.